# How to use a syscall in a shellcode without use `syscall` or `sysenter` for Linux x86-64, avoiding 0x0F bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I need to build a shellcode without the `0x0f` byte, the problem is that `syscall` and `sysenter` instructions have `0x0f` in their code machine. Are there any instruction that I can use to call `execve`?

Comment: AFAIK your only alternative is `int 0x80`, and [that doesn't work with pointer arguments except in very special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code).  On the other hand, if you're able to load and execute shellcode, the memory where it's located is probably writable and executable, so self-modifying code is an option.

Comment: Or, of course, you can try to call the `execve` function that's already in `libc`, or jump to a syscall instruction in the library or at some other known address in executable memory.  Since it's `execve` you don't care about getting control back afterwards.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68715350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some work here, I find one solution.
The idea behind was to construct a shellcode that has the capability to change himself, modify some bytes of machine code before they execute.

So what I did was to load `rip` into a register and put some bytes after. Then I change those bytes to `\x0f\x05` and in this way, I finally executed my shellcode.  I could have use a RIP-relative store instead of a RIP-relative LEA, after getting the desired bytes into a register (with mov + xor or shift, or various other ways.)